# Confusion with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am completely confused with implementing has_many :through for the dataset I am using.  So I have two tables - *scheme_master* and *scheme_detail*

*scheme_master* has these fields - *id, scheme_detail_id, primary_scheme_id*

*scheme_detail* has one relevant field - *id*

Every scheme in *scheme_master* has a primary scheme which is self referential to the *scheme_master* table. For instance, scheme 1 is the primary_scheme of schemes 1,2,3.

Relevant codes are as below

**scheme_master.rb**

```
class SchemeMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :scheme_detail
  has_many :child_schemes, class_name: "SchemeMaster", 
    foreign_key: :primary_scheme_id, primary_key: :id
end
```

**scheme_detail.rb**

```
class SchemeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scheme_master
end
```

My question is how do I access Scheme Details of all my child schemes?

Currently,

```
SchemeMaster.find(1).child_schemes
```

gives me all the child schemes - 1,2,3, but I want an association which would refer to scheme_detail of the child_schemes.  Thank you.

Comment: just try `has_many :scheme_details, through: :child_schemes`

Comment: It throws a stack level too deep error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `scheme_masters` table has `scheme_detail_id`, so you need to change this association

```
class SchemeMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scheme_detail
end

class SchemeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :scheme_master
end
```

Now, to fetch all `scheme_detail` of the `child_schemes`, do this

```
scheme_master = SchemeMaster.includes(child_schemes: :scheme_detail).where(id: 1).first
```

To fetch `scheme_detail` of `child_schemes`, you can do, `scheme_master.child_schemes.first.scheme_detail`.

Hope that helps!